# Removing fragments from an activity

Tags: android

```
FragmantClass rSum = new FragmantClass();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(rSum).commit();
```

I am trying to remove this fragment, when i load switch another fragment. The above fragment does not get removed. Here is the method i am calling to switch fragments.

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmantClass rSum = new FragmantClass();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(rSum).commit();
    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame)).commit();
```

Try this, it should work.

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
    if (oldFragment != null) { 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .remove(oldFragment).commit();
    }
    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
```

Comment: Is mContent a global variable?

Comment: @Thalaivar Thank you I found your answer for my app good and I have upvoted.

Answer (score 13):

In my personal case, I add and remove fragment this way:

```
 if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().
                remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).commit();
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a very straightforward solution for `SupportFragmentManager`. `FragmentManager` isn't quite as convenient, but still effective:

```
List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
// You might have to access all the fragments by their tag,
// in which case just follow the line below to remove the fragment
if (fragmentList == null) {
    // code that handles no existing fragments
}

for (Fragment frag : fragmentList )
{
   // To save any of the fragments, add this check
   // a tag can be added as a third parameter to the fragment when you commit it
   if (frag.getTag().equals("<tag-name")) {
      continue;
   }

   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
}
```

or, if you're forced to use it (but not recommended):

```
.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

If you're removing all fragments from the view multiple times, you might consider checking if the current frag is null or `isDetached()` or `isRemoving()` or you might get a `NullPointerExceptions`.

**Update 6-9-15:** The documentation for `getSupportFragmentManger().getFragments()` is apparently [hidden](https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags#@hide) now, but still works just fine in my code. Here's the screenshot of the documentation:

[image]

**Update 8-3-15**: If you're not using the support library for fragments, there is unfortunately no `getFragments()` available, but there are still a couple, more inconvenient, options.

1. Give each `fragment` a `tag` or `id` upon creation, and iterate through them to process each `fragment` as desired.
2. Create a listener using `onAttachListener` so each time a new `fragment` is attached to the `activity`, you can store that `fragment`, and then iterate through that data structure to process each `fragment` as desired.

When not using the `getSupportFragmentManager()`, to process a transaction you will need to use `getFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: Can you provide link to `getFragments()` method?

Comment: @IvanBlack, apparently there is no available link. I'm confident the documentation was available for it when I wrote this post, but the API shows it has hidden, thought it still works.

Answer (score -1):

More simple, you can replace the main content with an empty fragment, so that the main activity is viewed only.

```
getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.replace(main_content,new Fragment())
.commit();
```