# Delete fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to remove a fragment which from another activity than the one it was created at, when I create:

```
public FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


AlarmFragment frag = new AlarmFragment();
frag.setAlarmNumber(getAlarmsAmount());
getListaDeAlarmas().add(getAlarmsAmount(), frag);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.alarmListContainer, getListaDeAlarmas().get(alarmsAmount), "Alarm" + String.valueOf(getAlarmsAmount())).commit();
```

then I can access another activity FROM the fragment, lets say there is a button inside the fragment that opens another activity, now, staying at that activity I want to delete the fragment from which the activity was launched, i get a reference number to that fragment via the intent. So I tried:

```
        btDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Alarm" + String.valueOf(alarmNumber))).commit();
        }
    });
```

but it gives me a nullPointerException,

03-07 22:42:33.270 30993-30993/thehippo.rggmiranda.hiposleep E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5185)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I would really preciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do soemthing like this :

```
btDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
       Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Alarm" + String.valueOf(alarmNumber)));
       if(fragment != null) getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit(); 
    }
```

Let me know if it works.

### Edit

By the way did you debugged this line : `"Alarm" + String.valueOf(alarmNumber))` to verify that it's the `FragmentTag`?

If my answer doesn't work, try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002704/4385913).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering so fast. I tried with your suggestion but it did not work, I added an else to print a line for debugging to the if to see it the fragment is null and it is, 
"Alarm" + String.valueOf(alarmNumber)) is returning Alarm1 which is the tag of the fragment added

Comment: Keeps the same issue? Can you post the logcat that fires with my code

Comment: Sorry i hit enter instead of shift+enter and it added the comment, I edited it with some more info: 
I added an else to print a line for debugging to the if to see it the fragment is null and it is, "Alarm" + String.valueOf(alarmNumber)) is returning Alarm1 which is the tag of the fragment added

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda Solved the problem?